# How to multiply two elements of each pair from list of pairs - Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I want to make function which returns list of multiplied elements from each pair from list of pairs. For example:

```
>product [1,2] [3,4]
[3,8]
```

I want to do this using `list comprehension`. I tried something like this:

```
product :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
product xs ys = [x*y | z<-zip xs ys, (x, _)<-z, (_, y)<-z]
```

but it's not working. What should be changed?

Comment: `\xs ys -> sum [x*y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys]`

Comment: Note that this is the *raison d'être* for `zipWith`; `zipWith (*) xs ys` does exactly what you want.

Comment: I did it befor using `zipWith`, but I wanted to know how it can be done using `list comprehension` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should have one `<-` for each nested iteration. Since you only want to iterate over one list -- namely, `zip xs ys` -- there should be only one `<-`. Thus:

```
scalarproduct xs ys = sum [x*y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys]
```

You may also like the [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) function:

```
scalarproduct xs ys = sum (zipWith (*) xs ys)
scalarproduct = (sum .) . zipWith (*) -- may be readable, depending on your bent
```

Comment: If someone else has this problem and sees this answer: one key take-home point here is that you can pattern-match on the left hand side of a `<-`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to do this using list comprehension. [...]

My advice is: don't!  List comprehensions are a tool, and if they're not helping you, then use a different tool.

Simple solution:

```
product :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
product xs ys = zipWith (*) xs ys
```